# Magento customize search feature

Tags: php, magento, mage

I am trying to change the way that Magento assembles the catalogsearch_fulltext table in order to remove some information and to add more relevent information.  What files/classes are involved in editing this?

Alternatively, how could I make my own module/extension in order to write my own SQL queries to add/remove database from the catalogsearch_fulltext table.

I realize this is quite a project of a question but I would appreciate any leads to where I should edit since locating code in the core can be difficult.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [MTool](https://github.com/dankocherga/MTool) - this extension for Zend Framework tool helps you easily to rewrite Magento entities. The code that is responsible for search is located in folder app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch